# Testing connectivity in undirected Graph (using DFS)

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

I need to test which vertex is "important", where when a connected edge is removed, graph becomes disconnected. So my idea was try removing each edge then test the connectivity from 1 node to the other.

Example: Remove edge connecting 2 - 5. Then test connectivity from 2 - 5: `isConnected(2,5)`

```
  // DFS from node1 to node2
  boolean isConnected(int node1, int node2) {
    // keep track of (visited) status of nodes
    visited = new VertexState[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
      visited[i] = VertexState.NotVisited;

    // recursively test connectivity
    return _isConnected(node1, node2);
  }

  boolean _isConnected(int node1, int node2) {
    visited[node1] = VertexState.Visiting;
    if (node1 == node2) { // we found the node
      return true; 
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) { // for all children of node1
        if (AdjMatrix[node1][i] == 1 && visited[i] == VertexState.NotVisited) {
          if (_isConnected(i, node2)) { // test if child can reach node2
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      visited[node1] = VertexState.Visited;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

When I try it out with a simple graph, it works,but when I test it with a complex test case, it appears to produce wrong results. I have difficulties debugging as its a complex test case and can't draw it out.

---

**UPDATE**

If it helps just the pseudocode:

```
isConnected(node1, node2) 
    visited = new VertexState[V]
    for each v in visited
        v = NotVisited
    return _isConnected(node1, node2); // the recursion

_isConnected(node1, node2) 
    visited[node1] = Visiting
    if (node1 == node2) 
        return true // we found the node
    else 
        for each neighbour of node1
            if visited[neighbour] == NotVisited
                if_isConnected(neighbour, node2) 
                    return true
        visited[node1] = Visited
    return false
```

**UPDATE 2**

Full source **https://gist.github.com/3779445**, but with Adjacency List instead, it appears to work ... Not sure if its the most efficient algorithm tho ...

Comment: Is the adjacency matrix symmetric ? Please include the entire program (including how the adjacency matrix is constructed).

Comment: @krjampani, updated with full source, just that I think that 1 works fine already ...

Comment: @JiewMeng Does it work fine when the graph has a cycle, or a node passes itself as a neighbor?

Comment: this statement **where when a connected edge is removed, graph becomes disconnected** is not accurate! did you mean when a connected vertex is removed the graph becomes disconnected? because an edge must be connected between two nodes. In hyper graphs, an edge can connect more than two nodes, but at least an edge must be between two nodes.

Comment: @user1406062: paraphrase the statement as 'when an edge is removed, the number of (weakly) connected components increases' and it should be well-defined.